# VMware WKS guest/host bridged connection via loopback adapter

Tags: vmware, network-adapter, loopback

My guest on VMware workstation are bridged to host network and it works perfectly. guests see each other and able to communicate.
If I am not connected to my network it do not work because te host ethernet (static IP) do not have a connection.
Now i installed the MS Loopback adapter and like to use the adapter as follow:
host > loopback > vmware-guest
where the guests can communicate and if i drop of my homenetwork the guests should still be able to communicate with each other because the loopback adapter is available.
It's not working as I thought - can someone tell me how to configure it?

example:
host ip: 10.10.10.10  gw. 10.10.10.1
loopback: 10.10.10.11 gw: ?
guest#1: 10.10.10.12  gw: should be the loopback adapter?
guest#1: 10.10.10.13  gw: should be the loopback adapter?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: You can try use NAT networking .  That allows you to use VM networking when not connected to a router.

Comment: yeah, thought about it but with loopback adapter it should be possible.